# CPP Set default value for child class

Tags: c++, parent-child

Hello I'm already learning CPP and want to set a default value for child class but I don't know were to set it, I try many things and don't found information on internet. I'm looking for do less constructors ass possible.

I want to set by default the string arm by def0 when no paramters are set

```
class Parts {
    private:
        std::string _serial;
        bool _functionnal;
    public:
        Parts(std::string &serial, bool functional);
        std::string serial();
};

class Arms : public Parts {
    private:
        std::string _serial = "def0";
    public:
        Arms(std::string &serial, bool functionnal = true) : Parts(serial, functionnal)
        {
        }
};

Parts::Parts(std::string &serial, bool functional)
{
    this->_serial = serial;
    this->_functionnal = functional;
    std::cout << "Name set to: " << serial << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::string sample = "sample";
    Arms Ex(sample, false);
    Arms setAsDefault();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: std::string _serial{"def0"};

Comment: Change `Arms(std::string &serial` to `Arms(const std::string &serial = "def0"` ?

Comment: The `_serial` for the Arms class is another variable from the `_serial` of Parts

Comment: I can’t type up a complete answer right now, but what you’re looking for is the difference between a parameterized constructor (what you have) and a default constructor (or an overloaded one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the basis for using default parameters in place, however you are missing one crucial detail: you need to make the `string&` a const reference (otherwise you cannot assign it a default value)!

This requires you to change the constructor of `Parts` (both declaration and definition) to:

```
Parts(const std::string &serial, bool functional)
```

And change the `Arms` class to:

```
class Arms : public Parts {
    public:
        Arms(const std::string &serial = "def0", bool functionnal = true) : Parts(serial, functionnal)
        {
        }
};
```

One more detail is that `Arms setAsDefault();` does *not* create a new object, it instead declares a function returning an `Arms` (this is known as the most vexing parse problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Instead you need to change it to `Arms setAsDefault;`

EDIT: In fact you can simplify the constructor of `Parts` by using [member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), which will also prevent a default string construction (as pointed out by user4581301), e.g.:

```
Parts::Parts(const std::string &serial, bool functional) : _serial(serial), _functionnal(functional)
{
    std::cout << "Name set to: " << serial << std::endl;
}
```

So your example changed to do what you wanted is the following code

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Parts {
    private:
        std::string _serial;
        bool _functionnal;
    public:
        Parts(const std::string &serial, bool functional);
        std::string serial();
};

class Arms : public Parts {
    public:
        Arms(const std::string &serial = "def0", bool functionnal = true) : Parts(serial, functionnal)
        {
        }
};

Parts::Parts(const std::string &serial, bool functional) : _serial(serial), _functionnal(functional)
{
    std::cout << "Name set to: " << serial << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::string sample = "sample";
    Arms Ex(sample, false);
    Arms setAsDefault;

    return 0;
}
```

In order to have a constructor that takes only a `bool` (as asked in the comments) you need to provide another overload for the constructor, e.g. (using C++11 delegating constructors):

```
Arms(bool functionnal) : Arms("def0", functionnal) {}
```

EDIT2: As suggested by SergeyA an even better option is to pass the parameters by value and using `std::move` to move-construct the member variables. In this case your classes look like this:

```
class Parts {
    private:
        std::string _serial;
        bool _functionnal;
    public:
        Parts(std::string serial, bool functional);
        std::string serial();
};

class Arms : public Parts {
    public:
        Arms(std::string serial = "def0", bool functionnal = true) : Parts(std::move(serial), functionnal)
        {
        }

        Arms(bool functionnal) : Arms("def0", functionnal) {}
};

Parts::Parts(std::string serial, bool functional) : _serial(std::move(serial)), _functionnal(functional)
{
    // Note that `serial` will be empty after the move
    // so you need to access the member variable instead
    std::cout << "Name set to: " << _serial << std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: Can I talk you into showing off to the asker how to use the member initializer list to eliminate a default `string` construction in `Parts::Parts`?

Comment: This work as well, thanks for your help now I understand how it work. I just don't know how to give just the bolean in contructor like Arms test(false)

Comment: @BenjaminSolca for that you (unfortunately) need to overload the constructor (as C++ does not supported named parameters). Alternatively you could "invert" the problem where you don't have a constructor that accepts only a `string` by switching the order of the constructor parameters for `Arms`

Comment: Protip: make string value a non-reference and move from it!

Comment: @SergeyA could you please check if my second edit is correct? I'm not fully confident in my understanding of `std::move` and rvalues

Answer (score 0):

You could this:

```
class Parts {
    protected:
        std::string _serial;
    private :
        bool _functionnal;
    public:
        Parts(std::string &&serial, bool functional);
        std::string serial();
};

class Arms : public Parts {
    private:
        //std::string _serial = "def0"; this defines new variable which differs from parent's variable
    public:
        Arms(std::string &&serial="def0", bool functionnal = true) : Parts(serial, functionnal)
        {
        }
    };
```

Comment: This doesn't compile, you cannot bind a non-`const` reference type to an rvalue

Comment: Prefer indenting code blocks over delimiting with ``.

Comment: @UnholySheep you right, If use universal reference, I think this works

Comment: I try but can compile :/

Comment: Compiling is nice, but running without errors is golden.